# Database text in textarea shows <p>

Tags: php, database, wordpress

My situation is the following:

I have a database with a "description" column of type TEXT. In HTML, this column is represented as a textarea. When I'm entering the text:

[image: In the back-end]

Then, how it is stored in the database:

[image: Database storage]

Then, on the front-end:

[image: Front-end looks]

As you can see, it is displaying < p > tags.

This is the code for showing the textarea on both front-end as back-end:

```
 echo '<textarea class="form_textarea os-input" name="' . $this->GetName() . '" id="form_' . $this->GetName() . '"';
 $required = $this->GetRequired();
 if(isset($required) && $required == true)
 {
     echo ' required';
 }
 echo '>' . $this->GetValue() . '</textarea>';
```

- Both front-end and back-end use the same database, but in the front-end it looks different.
- Both front-end and back-end use the same code for showing the form (and thereby the textarea)
- There is no special escaping at all. No use of nl2br or etc.
- I'm using WordPress

**This is the weird part:** When I print it on the screen, without textarea:

- The back-end shows: "This is some text", in the Chrome dev tool, you do see the newlines, but no < p >.
- The front-end shows: "This(newline)is(newline)some text", in the Chrome dev tool, you do see the < p > tags.

The code for getting the values from the database are also the same in front-end and back-end. This can't be a "client side" thing right?

Comment: Both front-end and back-end use the same database? That's kinda odd because only the back-end has interaction with the database.

Comment: Check that the source is correct, don't rely on browser dev tools to debug server side output.

Comment: @Daan Maybe the wrong word usage but on both "sides" the value is part of a form and on both sides it can be changed.